# Find files containing a specific string and delete line with this string - SSH, SED

Tags: bash, sed

I have a multiple files "header.php" in multiple catalogues.
Some of them contain string "ASDF1234" and some of them not.

I want to search in all "header.php" files with string "ASDF1234" and delete whole line containing it.

How can I do that with sed?

Comment: how is this one realted to ssh?

Comment: Umm.. By VPS? Or Dedicated server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way also

```
find  -iname "header.php" -exec  sed -i '/ASDF1234/d' {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

```
   find -iname "header.php"  - It will find all header.php files
   -exec                     - Execute the sed command and passing the argument for all the header.php files
   sed -i '/ASDF1234/d'      - If the /ASDF1234/ content match delete the line.
```

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot. Working great!